# Is Flink aware of the Kafka partition addition during runtime

Tags: apache-flink

I have a question aboult Flink-Kafka Source:

When a flink application starts up after restored from checkpoint, and runs well.

During running, serveral Kafka partitions are added to the Kafka topic, will the running flink application be aware of these added partitions and read them without manual effort? or I have to restart the application and let flink be aware of these partition during startup?

Could you please point to me the code where Flink handles Kafka partitions change if adding partitions doesn't need manual effort. I didn't find the logic in the code.

Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

Looks that Flink will be aware of new topic and new partition during runtime,the method call sequence is:

`FlinkKafkaConsumerBase#run`

`FlinkKafkaConsumerBase#runWithPartitionDiscovery`

`FlinkKafkaConsumerBase#createAndStartDiscoveryLoop`

It the last method, it will kick off a new thread to discover new topics/partitions periodically